# Xcode how to make a curve?

Tags: core-graphics

Im making an iPhone app, and I'm wondering how to make a curve if i e.g. got 3 points

```
(3,2)
(4,3)
(5,4)
```

how can i make a curve?

Comment: Retag your question with the graphics library you are using. This is not an Xcode question, and we need to know what graphics libary you are using to have a chance at helping.

Comment: There is not enough data here to really help you. Look into Coregraphics..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIs like `CGPathAddCurveToPoint`, `CGContextAddCurveToPoint`, `CGContextAddArc`, `CGPathAddArc`, etc. would be a start if you are using CoreGraphics.